# My angular application was working very well , but suddenly I ran into this problem

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack

My application was working without any problem , all the routes work very well and suddenly I ran this problem

```
Build at: 2023-11-21T11:19:17.664Z - Hash: ff89e45d55bc422e - Time: 25947ms

./node_modules/express/lib/view.js:72:13-25 - Warning: Critical dependency: the request 
of a dependency is an expression

./node_modules/express/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:270:11-33 - Warning: Module not 
found: Error: Can't resolve 'async_hooks' in 'C:\Users\ONS\Desktop\angular- 
16\node_modules\express\node_modules\raw-body'

./node_modules/on-finished/index.js:191:11-33 - Warning: Module not found: Error: Can't 
resolve 'async_hooks' in 'C:\Users\ONS\Desktop\angular-16\node_modules\on-finished'



./node_modules/destroy/index.js:15:17-41 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 
'fs' in 'C:\Users\ONS\Desktop\angular-16\node_modules\destroy'

./node_modules/etag/index.js:21:12-31 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 
'fs' in 'C:\Users\ONS\Desktop\angular-16\node_modules\etag'

./node_modules/express/lib/application.js:22:11-26 - Error: Module not found: Error: 
Can't resolve 'http' in 'C:\Users\ONS\Desktop\angular-16\node_modules\express\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by 
default.     
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for 
it.     

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "http": require.resolve("stream-http") }'
    - install 'stream-http'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "http": false }
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on 
http://localhost:4200/ **

× Failed to compile.
```

I add this to my webpac.config.js file but it's the same problem !!

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  resolve: {
  fallback: {
  assert: require.resolve('assert/'),
  fs: false,
  http: require.resolve('stream-http'),
  net: require.resolve('net'),
  crypto: require.resolve('crypto-browserify'),
  path: require.resolve('path-browserify'),
  stream: require.resolve('stream-browserify'),
  zlib: require.resolve('browserify-zlib'),
  querystring: require.resolve('querystring-es3'),
  util: require.resolve('util/'),
  },
 },
 plugins: [
 new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  process: 'process/browser',
  Buffer: ['buffer', 'Buffer'],
 }),
],

};
```

Comment: Have you tried deleting ```node_modules``` and ```package-lock.json```, then installing them with ```npm install``` after configuring webpack file ?

Comment: Have you tried to follow the suggestion shows in the terminal ? `If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:`